# How to solve - Componets overlapping

Tags: reactjs

`SignUp` component is over `Home` component in one screen. 
I have a protected route, the user will start in the `SignUp` page, when condition is true (`userSignedUp` is being updated at SignUp) it will transfer to the `Home`  component but the `SignUp` component is still on the screen and active (the inputs and buttons). 
So I see two components one over the other.

 Anyone knows how to solve this issue ?
I hope I explained it right.

**App.js**

```js
 return (
    <div className='App-div'>
      <GuardedRoute path='/home' auth={userSignedUp}>
        <Home userIDNumber={userID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
      </GuardedRoute>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/signup'>
          <SignUp setUserNumber={setUserID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
```

**GuardedRoute.js**

```js
function GuardedRoute({ children, auth }) {
  return (
    <Route
      render={() => {
        console.log('children or /signup');
        return auth ? children : <Redirect to='/signup' />;
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

## Update

You can check the project here

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-water-ef5xp)

Answer (score 0):

Since I'd spent considerable time in your app earlier, I tried to reproduce this issue.

It is best to have `<BrowserRouter />` at the top level and the route definitions in one file.

`<App />` is passed as a child to `<BrowserRouter />` in index.js, this signup route is defined in App and again the signup uses BrowserRouter. It is repetitive. Consider having your route definitions in App.js only.

Overlapping happens because of the same `exact` key. Route definitions in the right order with the matching paths will not throw this issue.

Is there any specific reason why you have your route definitions in two different files (App and Signup)? what's the need for this signup component other than just redirection?

I've refactored your code to have all routes in App. [Working App Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-pike-nfzxu)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext } from 'react';
import { Redirect, Route, Switch, Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import SignUp from '../components/SignUp/SignUp';
import CreatePass from '../components/SignUp/CreatePassword';
import Home from '../components/Home/Home';
import GuardedRoute from './GuardedRoute';
import MobileNum from '../components/SignUp/MobileNum';
import IdentNumber from '../components/SignUp/IdentificationNum';
import Header from '../components/SignUp/Header';
import './App.css';

const useStateWithLocalStorage = () => {
  const [userSignedUp, setIfSignUp] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('signUpBool'))
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('signUpBool', JSON.stringify(userSignedUp));
    console.log(
      'localStorage.getItem(signUpBool)',
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('signUpBool'))
    );
  }, [userSignedUp]);

  return [userSignedUp, setIfSignUp];
};

const pathArray = ['/signup/mobile', '/signup/idnumber', '/signup/password'];

const App = () => {

  const [userID, setUserID] = useState('');
  const [userSignedUp, setIfSignUp] = useStateWithLocalStorage();


  return (
    <div className='App-div'>
      <Header />
      {userSignedUp ? <Redirect to='/home' /> : <Redirect exact to='/' />}
      <Switch>
        <Redirect exact from='/' to="/signup/mobile" />
        <Route path='/signup/mobile' component={MobileNum} />
        <Route path='/signup/idnumber'>
          <IdentNumber setPersonalID={setUserID} />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/signup/password'>
          <CreatePass
            setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp}
            pathsArray={pathArray}
          />
        </Route>
        <Route path='/signup'>
          <SignUp setUserNumber={setUserID} setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp} />
        </Route>
        <GuardedRoute path='/home' auth={userSignedUp}>
          <Home
            userIDNumber={userID}
            setIfSignUp={setIfSignUp}
          />
        </GuardedRoute>
     
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You could modify `<Redirect exact from='/' to="/signup/mobile" />` to the desired behavior for a logged in user.

Comment: Hi deechris! You should erase the - userSignedUp ? <Redirect to='/home' /> : <Redirect exact to='/' its a mistake I didn’t clear. It ruins everything.

Comment: "Is there any specific reason why you have your route definitions in two different files (App and Signup)?" - **Answer** `Signup` must contain `<Router history={history}>`,  whithout it no route/navigation will happen. I learend that in other question and that is very important. (!) Plus I'm plannig a big application with many components and the components render must be splitted !

Comment: I'm not going with the easy code-solution, ( it might look complicated at the end),but I'm doing what is good in the long range.

Comment: Oh, I see, your app is now easy to modify as per best practices, it will be tedious to refactor once it is built or if you encounter router-related issues later. When I worked on ur app, I felt the SignUp component was redundant.

Comment: I edited the codesandbox, it has wrong code in it. What do you mean redundant? it must be separated like that.

Comment: when I visit localhost:3000, I land on SignUp which redirects me to /signup/mobile. Why have a component just to redirect? That's why I said redundant.

Comment: Yea Try to go to /signup/mobile from App.js, nothing will move, thats the truth.